# on a cisco router can you run a tunnel and a vpn on the same interface and have vpn traffic pass over the tunnel

Tags: vpn, cisco, routing, tunneling

The problem I am having is I have a point to point tunnel from site A to site B.  Remote users connect to site A via VPN.  I would like them to be able to send traffic over the tunnel to site B.  Is this possible to do?  The Tunnel sets up fine and I can connect to the VPN just fine ... I think I have added all of the rules to allow traffic to pass.  A google search seemed to indicate that there may be problems because this is the same interface.  Let me know if segments from the router configuration would be useful. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you saying that the user-to-site VPN is terminated at the same device that terminates the site-to-site VPN, or is the user-to-site VPN terminated by some device behind the site-to-site VPN router?

Comment: They both terminate on the the same device and interface

Answer (score 1):

An IOS router ought to handle that fine. A PIX w/ OS version prior to 7 isn't. A PIX w/ OS 7 or an ASA should able to handle it, but you'll need to put in a "same-security-traffic permit intra-interface" in the config (at least on an ASA) to handle it.

Comment: Its running IOS 12.4 so it sounds like it should be possible

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the [config](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk583/tk372/technologies_configuration_example09186a0080094685.shtml) that I needed to do that here. I'll Try to remember to post after I get it debugged and let people know if it worked.